# how to show user name with id from 2 tables in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

when i send a letter, i catch sender_id with `auth()->user()->id` and save into the letter table

but just user_id will save, like 2 or 3 ...

how can i show user name in my view ?

list.blade.php :

```
<tr>
     <td>{{ $letter->sender_id }}</td>
</tr>
```

LetterController.php -> public function index :

```
$letters = Letter::latest()->paginate(10)->where('recieve_id', '=', auth()->user()->id);
```

LetterController.php -> public function store :

```
Letter::create([
    'sender_id' => auth()->user()->id,
]);
```

letter table :

```
$table->string('sender_id');
```

and i have a relation but i dont know it is correct or not

Letter.php :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'sender_id');
}
```

User.php:

```
public function letter()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Letter::class);
}
```

UPDATE :

in veiw when use this :

```
<td>{{ $letter->user->name }}</td>
```

but i have this error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.sender_id' in 
'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`sender_id` = 1 limit 
1) (View: D:\Web\Projects\automation\resources\views\Letter\list.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In view like this:
{{ $letter->user->name }}

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.sender_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`sender_id` = 1 limit 1) (View: D:\Web\Projects\automation\resources\views\Letter\list.blade.php)

Comment: Change

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'sender_id');
}

To

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'sender_id', 'id');
}

Comment: i try this but also i have an error : Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: D:\Web\Projects\automation\resources\views\Letter\list.blade.php)

Comment: $letters = Letter::with('user')->latest()->paginate(10)->where('recieve_id', '=', auth()->user()->id);